# SQL Avoid summing rows multiple times based on LIKE expression

Tags: sql, aggregate, mutual-exclusion

I have a table with bank transactions with columns id, tDate, description, cashOut, cashIn. I want to see how I spend my money, specifically at Amazon and a shop called Mazo, so I want a result like this:

```
Month   Amazon   Mazo   Total
1       100      200    300
```

I attempted this:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(tDate) AS Month,
    SUM(IF(description LIKE '%amazon%',cashOut,0)) AS Amazon,
    SUM(IF(description LIKE '%mazo%',cashOut,0)) AS Mazo,
    SUM(cashOut) AS Total
FROM `transactions` 
GROUP BY Month
```

However, I got the following:

```
Month   Amazon   Mazo   Total
1       100      300    300
```

The problem with this SQL query is that the sum of "mazo"-transactions is wrong, because it also adds up the "amazon" transactions.

I want the selection of the transactions to sum to be mutually exclusive or something like that, so that each transaction is part of only one of the SUMs above (without resorting to PHP or similar). (My tables contain much more data than this, and I have lots of search criteria, so it doesn't suffice to use '% mazo %' as search word. I need a general solution to the problem.)

Does anybody have a suggestion?

*Details of the table and its data:*

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`tDate` date NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`cashOut` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
`cashIn` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB 

INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `tDate`, `description`, `cashOut`, `cashIn`) VALUES
(1, '2010-01-05', 'amazon', '100', '0'),
(4, '2010-01-15', 'mazo', '200', '0');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create mutually exclusive groups by flagging each row in an inner query and then filtering on that:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(tDate) AS Month,
    SUM(IF(flag = 'amazon', cashOut, 0)) AS Amazon,
    SUM(IF(flag = 'mazo', cashOut, 0)) AS Mazo,
    SUM(IF(flag = 'other', cashOut, 0)) AS Other,
    SUM(cashOut) AS Total
FROM (
    SELECT tDate, cashOut,
        CASE
            WHEN description LIKE '%amazon%' THEN 'amazon'
            WHEN description LIKE '%mazo%' THEN 'mazo'
            ELSE 'other'
        END AS flag
    FROM transactions
) x
GROUP BY Month
```

That way you will never count the same transaction twice if some transaction will match more than one keyword. If you don't want to repeat the same keyword twice in query and can live with a list looking like that:

```
Month   What     Sum
1       amazon   100
2       mazo     200
```

then you can use:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(tDate) AS Month,
    flag AS What,
    SUM(cashOut) AS Total
FROM (
    SELECT tDate, cashOut,
        CASE
            WHEN description LIKE '%mazo%' THEN 'mazo'
            WHEN description LIKE '%amazon%' THEN 'amazon'
            ELSE 'other'
        END AS flag
    FROM transactions
) x
GROUP BY Month, flag
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, much appreciated! (As for the second suggestion, it won't do in my case, as I need to know the sum for every month for every search key.)

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for strings that contain `mazo`.  If you just want Mazo, change:

```
SUM(IF(description LIKE '%mazo%',cashOut,0)) AS Mazo,
```

to

```
SUM(IF(description = 'mazo',cashOut,0)) AS Mazo,
```

EDIT: In reply to your comment, you can use regex `[[:<:]]` to search for [word boundaries](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/regexp.html):

```
SUM(IF(description REGEXP '[[:<:]]mazo[[:>:]]',cashOut,0)) AS Mazo,
```

Comment: No, I want strings that contain Mazo. I see that I didn't mention that transaction descriptions are usually some longer string, such as "53,12 New York Mazo blabla".

Comment: @Yngvar Kristiansen: Perhaps it's best to search for word boundaries, which match beginning of string, spaces, comma's and so on.  Example added to answer.

Comment: The regexp still doesn't make a mutually exclusive result. I don't want to sum a transaction more than once.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    MONTH(tDate) AS Month,
    SUM(IF(description LIKE '%amazon%',cashOut,0)) AS Amazon,
    SUM(IF(description LIKE '%mazo%' AND description NOT LIKE '%amazon%',cashOut,0)) AS Mazo,
    SUM(cashOut) AS Total
FROM `transactions` 
GROUP BY Month
```

Comment: This works. However, say I had 50 search words like amazon and mazo, the SQL would be very large. Is there a more general or elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I would suggest to add some sort of redundant identifier in a column at the time of insert. This would mean the calculations are only done once, at insert. E.g.: you add 'AMZ' for Amazon, 'MAZO', etc Then you only need to do equality comparisons. If you want to take it even further you can use integer identifiers because the comparisons would be a lot faster that way (1 = Amazon, 2 =  Mazo, etc)

Comment: If you have 50 search words, then it would be best to create a table of vendors, and store the vendor code in each transaction. Then summing the expenses by vendor would be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Use `=` with the exact text, not `like` and simply by losing the `IF`. Try this:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(tDate) AS Month,
    SUM((description = 'Amazon') * cashOut) AS Amazon,
    SUM((description = 'Mazo') * cashOut) AS Mazo,
    SUM(cashOut) AS Total
FROM `transactions`
GROUP BY Month
```